# Return Date of Max Value Pivot Table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, pivot-table

Pivot table below sorts the Sales ID by rows, Max Sales Amount, and Date in the values field. Goal is to return the Date of the Max Sales Amount.

Need a formula to find the Date related to the Max Sales Amount? Index/Match/Vlookup in Column G or in the "Calculated Field" within the pivot table?

[image]

Comment: What is "Max of Date"? Why is it a value field and not just a Row field?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That does return the correct date if moved to the Row field. However, doing that makes the Pivot Chart I export extremely hard to read as it modifies the x-axis. Leaving the Date in the Values field and making it a secondary axis on the pivot chart works way better.